# Warning for unsaved files in notepadpp?

Tags: windows

When I have unsaved files in notepadpp and I close the program it does not warn me.

Is there a setting for such a warning?

I did not find anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Settings -> Preferences -> Backup
2. Disable Remember current session for next launch
3. Disable Enable session snapshot and periodic backup

From [Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#:%7E:text=backup%20on%20save.-,Session%20snapshot%20and%20periodic,not%20enable%20this%20option.,-This%20is%20not) (emphasis mine):

> Session snapshot and periodic backup
>
> - Remember current session for next launch: the current session is the current list of open files. The next time you run Notepad++, it will open with that same list of files
> - Enable session snapshot and periodic backup: this will auto-save your changed file once every N seconds to the listed directory (default to %AppData%\Notepad++\backup).
>
>   - It is not possible to select this option without ☐ Remember current session ... also being active
>   - This is also how you enable Notepad++ to remember unsaved changes
>   - This will allow you to exit Notepad++ and resume, remembering changes to files that hadn’t been intentionally saved
>   - When you exit Notepad++ with unsaved changes, Notepad++ will not ask you to save changes. It will just keep the periodic backup file, and reload from there rather than from the normal disk location for the file
>   - **If you want Notepad++ to ask to you save edited files every time you close the file or exit Notepad++, do not enable this option.**

Comment: I did point 2 and it now asks me. I don't know about point 3. I didn't find this point. But I have German as language and maybe this was the reason I didn't find it.